# Which datepicker does EveryBlock utilize?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, controls

I've found a great datepicker on EveryBlock's web site:

http://ui-patterns.com/userset/553/image/2955#focus

Does anybody know which control do they use and is it available as a standalone control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a custom-made one, from looking at [the JavaScript source](http://media.everyblock.com/vd619256cc10a319716533c93a25df7af/scripts/combined.js). There is a `function Calendar(a, b)` with a lot of code, and something called `CustomFilter`. They are building their stuff on top of jQuery, though.

Comment: Yes, that looks like it. I browsed through a dozen of jQuery calendars and none of them was similar to the EveryBlock's.

Comment: As a general tip, the online JS beautifier is great for minified sources like the one above. You can see their `draw` methods in "human-readable" form. Check out http://jsbeautifier.org/